# Not getting channel 1 in an Face images even though in Grey-colour

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation

[image: Original image]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1U9eF.png)

Code :-

```
originalImage = imread('greyface1.jpg');
[rows, columns, numberOfColorChannels] = size(originalImage)
if numberOfColorChannels > 1
    rgbImage = originalImage;
else
    fprintf('It is not really RGB like we expected - it is grayscale.\n');
    rgbImage = cat(3, originalImage, originalImage, originalImage);
end
```

Not getting channel 1 in an Face images even though in Grey-colour. Converted the code from rgb2grey but getting same. I am sharing Image, Code, Output i have got.

Comment: So your problem is that the loaded image, before any conversion, has 3 channels? Isn't that to be expected? What happened when you convert the image with `rgb2gray()`?

Comment: By the way, you could have just edited your previous question so that it could be reopened. It's also not a good idea to post images of your output (or input or code). Copy and pasted text is preferred.